# P2Pool for Dogecoin error - too many open files

Tags: p2pool, dogecoin

I'm running a private p2pool instance mining for Dogecoin. Both the Dogecoin client (equivalent of bitcoind) and p2pool run on the same server. After some time, between half an hour and days, the pool stops mining and shows the following Twisted error:

```
Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectBindError: Couldn't bind: 24: Too many open files.
```

How do I solve this?